# In Python, how to efficiently extract sublist from a list based on a list of 0/1, where locations with 1 is selected?

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have a list called `all=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`, and another list called `sub=[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, I want to create a new list based on `all` by extracting only elements whose corresponding value in the list named `sub` is 1, i.e., I want to generate aa=[0,2,4,5]. It would be great if this could be done as fast as possible as I need to repeat this more than 10 millions of times.

I've tried the following two ways:

(1).

```
aa=all[sub]
```

But I got the message "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list"

(2).

```
bv=list(map(bool,sub))
aa=all[bv]
```

But I got the same error message.

How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is this Python?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a simple list comprehension:

```
aa = [x for x,s in zip(lst,sub) if s == 1]
```

You would need to time it to see if it is fast enough for your needs.

(As an aside using `all` as the list name overwrites the built-in function with the same name).

Comment: Thanks, John! This is very helpful. I also have a question regarding the second method I used. We know that we could always filter a list with a boolean list, so I have a hard time understanding why the second method I tried didn't work.

Comment: I just tested the time, and your method is extremely fast. Another question is, how to generalize your method to deal with selecting rows from matrices? For example, lst being a 10 by 2 numpy array, and I want the rows corresponding to 1 in sub being selected.

Comment: You second method produces a `bv` which is neither an integer nor a slice expression hence `all[bv]` fails. I program in R sometimes where things like `x[v]` where `v` is a vector is an arbitrary vector is possible. Unfortunately, Python list indexing isn't as flexible. Since pandas is partially modeled on R, perhaps there is something there which gives similar functionality. I don't have a lot of experience with numpy so don't know any idiomatic way to change my answer to that context. Perhaps you could ask another question using the `numpy` tag.